# Should I use the same tense throughout the sentence?

Tags: past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

In my English exam, I have written the sentence:

> There **were** always some people who **judge** the others by their appearance.

One of my friends said that I should use *judged* instead of *judge* since I am talking about past. Which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is correct. *judged* is the correct verb form when you are talking about the past. If the sentence started with **There *are* always some people...**, then *judge* would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your friend is correct. However, verb-form need not be consistent across a sentence in all cases. For starters, even if a whole sentence is the in past, there are different ways of putting things in the past. Then the verb might shift to the progressive (**judging**) or even back into the bare infinitive (**judge**).

(Also, unless there's something in context that makes it right, the *the* on "the others" is extraneous and incorrect.)

> "There were always some people who judged others by their appearance."
>
> "There were always some people who were judging others by their appearance."
>
> "There were always some people who would judge others by their appearance."